# How to make flask stream output line by line?

Tags: python, flask

I have a generator function that generates CSVs and as per [Flask's documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/streaming/) I pass that function inside the Response object.

```
app.route("/stream")
...
def generate():

        yield ",".join(result.keys()) #Header

        for row in result:
            yield ",".join(["" if v is None else str(v) for v in row])

return current_app.response_class(stream_with_context(generate()))
```

When I go to read the response inside my `Request` I get response back as one giant string as opposed to getting line by line so it can be written to a `csvwriter`

```
s = requests.Session()

with s.get(
    urllib.parse.urljoin(str(current_app.config["API_HOST_NAME"]), str("/stream")),
    headers=None,
    stream=True,
) as resp:
    for line in resp.iter_lines():
        if line:
            print(line) #All the rows are concatenated in one big giant String
            cw.writerow(str(line, "utf-8").split(","))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the docs you posted:

```
yield f"{','.join(row)}\n"  # <=== Newline at the end!
```

the new line is provided in the yield statement. If you don't put a new line, you won't get one in the response. Just add it with  `+ '\n'`.